# OpenGL PBO and texture objects: Do I need to allocate memory for both

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, texture2d

I am using a pixel buffer object and texture as follows:

```
// Initialize PBO
Gluint _buffer;
Glenum target = GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER
glGenBuffers(1, &_buffer);
if (_buffer) {
    glBindBuffer(target, _buffer);
    glBufferData(target, rows * cols * 4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
    glBindBuffer(target, 0);
}
```

Now I load the data into the PBO as follows:

```
glBindBuffer(target, _buffer);
GLubyte * data = (GLubyte *)glMapBuffer(target, GL_READ_WRITE);
memcpy(data, my_image_data, rows * cols * 4);
glUnmapBuffer(target);
glBindBuffer(target, 0);
```

My question is when I map this PBO to a texture, do I need to allocate memory for the texture as well (essentially doing a copy). Or can I simply map it without any allocation of memory.

```
// Without allocation of texture memory
GLuint t;
glBindBuffer(target, t);
glGenTextures(1, &t);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, _cols, _rows,
                    GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glBindBuffer(target, 0);
```

Or should I also have the memory allocation of the texture. So a call like:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, cols, rows, 0, GL_BGRA, 
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *)NULL);
```

after glBindTexture().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, **you must allocate storage** (via `glTexStorage` or `glTexImage` or `glCopyTexImage` etc.) before being able to upload texture data into an image.

If you attempt to use `glTexSubImage2D` on a texture without allocated storage it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes you have to allocate textures individually. Unfortunately in OpenGL it is not possible to bind an existing memory region to a texture sampler and use it like that. There have been multiple attempts in getting it into OpenGL (superbuffers and the likes, around 2004).

The ability to use the same memory region with different functional units is one of the big things people are eager for with the Vulkan API.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there would be a way to lock the memory region and perhaps use it but thank you for confirming that it is not possible.

Comment: Even before, with `GL_APPLE_client_storage` (2002) :) These days you can use a texture buffer object.